# Queue to upload list of images one after another in Android Using Retrofit2

Tags: android, queue, retrofit2, image-uploading, image-upload

I am creating an app where user can upload images, I am uploading images one after another using retrofit. Right now I am running a for loop for it, but it is not a good way to do it. I cannot use service because I need progress dialog as well on main screen to let user know upload is happening. Is there a way to maintain some kind of queue to handle this?

Comment: why don't you upload them in a single call?

Comment: @FaisalNaseer requirement is such that it has to be one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and Retrofit to do it it can be done with the retrofit alone but as I have already done it with AsyncTask have a look.

```
public class AsyncBulkUpload extends AsyncTask<Boolean, Integer, Boolean> {

    private ApiInterface mApiInterface;

    private Call<ResponseBody> mResponseBodyCall;
    private Response<ResponseBody> mResponseBody;
    private RequestBody mRequestBody;
    private Service mService;

    private Bitmap mItemBitmap;

    public int mTotalCount = 0;

    public AsyncBulkUpload(Service service) {
        mService=service;
        mApiInterface = ApiClient.getClient(mService.getApplicationContext()).create(ApiInterface.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mTotalCount = sClosetList.size();
        //Show you dialog

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Boolean... itsRetry) {
        /**
         *Check if its retry or not
         * if yes don't get the placeholder ids.
         * or else hit and get place holder ids
         */

        //Run your loop here.
        return upload();
    }

    private Boolean upload() {

        if (isCancelled())
            return false;

        if (sClosetList.size() > 0) {

            //Item image
            try {
                mItemBitmap = Glide.with(mService.getApplicationContext())
                        .load(sClosetList.get(0).mItemImage)
                        .asBitmap()
                        .into(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL)
                        .get();


            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //Coudnt get the image so cant go further
                LogPrint.printError("WHILE GETTING BITMPAP");
                return false;
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                //Coudnt get the image so cant go further
                LogPrint.printError("WHILE GETTING BITMPAP");
                return false;
            }



            FormBody.Builder bodyBuilder = new FormBody.Builder();

            bodyBuilder.add("image", mItemBitmap);

            /**
             *Label image can or can not be available
             */



            mRequestBody = bodyBuilder.build();
            mResponseBodyCall = mApiInterface.uploadProducts(mRequestBody);
            try {
                mResponseBody = mResponseBodyCall.execute();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }

            if (!mResponseBody.isSuccessful()) {
                /**
                 *Some server error try again
                 */
                return false;
            } 
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        //Update your progressbar
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        //Dismiss the dialog
        if (aBoolean) {
            Toast.makeText(mService, R.string.uploaded_successful, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }



}
```

Comment: I don't understand how this code can be used to upload multiple images??

Comment: Do you want to upload multiple images in one go? You can upload images one after another using above method where I have commented run your loop here, there you will have to put your own logic and the code written in the upload function does the work of uploading, and to show the dialog box you can check out the comment which I have mentioned.